# Optaplanner with TimeWindow

Tags: java, drools-planner, optaplanner

I need help for one question with Time Window
I am beginner with Optaplanner
For object VrpTimeWindowedCustomer
we have some fieldes: readyTime, dueTime and serviceDuration
In my problem I have 3 deliveries
One up to 6:15 pm
another up to 6:30 pm
and  another up to 6:45 pm
how should I fill in the fields  readyTime and dueTime?

Answer (score 2):

"up to" are dueTime.

So for example:

- delivery A from 8 am (= readyTime) till 6:15 pm (= dueTime)
- delivery B from 8 am (= readyTime) till 6:30 pm (= dueTime)
- delivery C from 8 am (= readyTime) till 6:45 pm (= dueTime)

serviceDuration is how long they 'll stay at that location. For example 20 minutes.